# Custom UITableCell Swipe

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a customized UITableCell, and want to enable the swipe function to show delete button, how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make swipe-to-delete work you need to implement these three methods:

```
tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:
tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:
tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:
```